# Node Redis EC2 errconnrefuced

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

There's some strange behavior i've found with node_redis on Aws EC2.

Let's say i have two EC2 instances.

First one is used for DB (Redis, MYSQL, etc.) and it has an IP like so `ip-1-1-1-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal`

Second one is for app based on NodeJS and it's IP is `ip-2-2-2-2.eu-west-1.compute.internal`

In the Security Groups i've added this:

```
6379    sg-351a0441 (default)
6379    sg-333b9044 (quicklaunch-0)
```

I use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) module to communicate with Redis. I need to connect from one instance to another.

So now i (probably) can connect to Redis (first server) from another one:

```
redis = require('redis');
client = redis.createClient(6379, 'ip-1-1-1-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal');
```

But this way causes error:

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
```

It tries to connect (!) to `127.0.0.1` istead of `1.1.1.1`.
I've said "OK. Let's try another way!"

```
redis = require('redis');
client = redis.createClient(6379, '1.1.1.1');
```

And.. BANG! The same error here:

```
Error: Redis connection to 1.1.1.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
```

So, maybe full redis url will help?

```
redis = require('redis');
client = redis.createClient(6379, 'redis://1.1.1.1');
```

No :(

```
Error: Redis connection to redis://10.248.118.246:6379 failed - getaddrinfo EADDRINFO
```

And same one when using internal url:

```
Error: Redis connection to redis://ip-1.1.1.1.eu-west-1.compute.internal:6379 failed - getaddrinfo EADDRINFO
```

So, what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look: [Node.js http.request fails with Error: getaddrinfo EADDRINFO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565209/node-js-http-request-fails-with-error-getaddrinfo-eaddrinfo)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, i know the meaning of this error. But i use same addresses to connect to redis from RoR app and it works fine.